# How to obtain numerical eigenvectors of a symbolic matrix provided the ranges of the matrix elements are known using Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, sympy, numerical-methods, eigenvector

I have a 2 by 2 symbolic matrix M = Matrix([[a, b],[c, d]]) where the numerical ranges of its elements {a,b,c,d} are known. Is there known numerical methods in python that returns the ranges of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of M?

I am new to python so I tried using the sympy.diagonalize() method `P, D = M.diagonalize()` but it seems that is working only if the elements are fixed (not ranges).
Here is a sample code of this:

```
from sympy import *
a, b, c, d = symbols('a b c d')
M = Matrix([[a, b],[c, d]])
#The ranges of the elements
a_min = 1
a_max = 4     

b_min = 0.5
b_max = 7

c_min = -1
c_max = 1

d_min = -1
d_max = 1

for a in linspace(a_min,a_max,5):
    for b in linspace(b_min,b_max,5):
        for c in linspace(c_min,c_max,5):
            for d in linspace(d_min,d_max,5):
                P, D = M.diagonalize() 
print(P)
print(D)
```

Is there a way to obtain P and D with numerical ranges for each element?

Thanks a lot

Best regards

Comment: This is not a really a well-posed question. If we suppose that the eigenvalues are real for all possible values in the given range then it can make sense to find a intervals of possible values for them. Eigenvectors do not have a defined magnitude or sign though so the interval for a non-zero real component of an eigenvector is basically from `-oo` to `oo`. I think that whatever you are ultimately trying to do there is probably a better approach than by using what you are asking for here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The eigenvectors of the symbolic matrix above are given as a function of the parameters a, b, c and d (This is actually what we obtain when we execute the above code). So, I cant see how there should be infinite range of the eigenvectors because the ranges of the parameters is limited. I tried to use the for loop to scan over the parameters but it still returned symbolic eigenvectors.

Comment: Your matrix `M` still contains symbolic variables, only that in the loops you have re-purposed the variable names for new, unrelated floating-point variables. These are unused, do not magically appear in `M`. You would need to construct the matrix directly from them, or use the `subst` function or method.

Comment: Any multiple of an eigenvector is an eigenvector so if there is an eigenvector with first component 1 then there are also eigenvectors with first component equal to any real or complex number. Also both the eigenvalues and eigenvectors can be complex in which case it isn't clear what you mean by an "interval". Also in the case of repeated roots it's possible that any nonzero vector is an eigenvector. What you are asking for here does not make mathematical sense so I think take a step back and explain why you even want this in the first place.

Comment: OK. Let me rephrase my question. Is a numerical diagonalization of a symbolic matrix M where the only information provided is the ranges of the elements in M possile? (with python).

Answer (score -1):

You can using the function in Python to solve the eigenvalue/eigenvector problem for a square array is the `eig` function in `numpy.linalg`.
Reference more: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html